# Extending bootstrap typeahead with bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm creating a rails site using the [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/) and it works fine. 
I'm also successfully initializing the typeahead on my js.erb:

```
$container.find('.typeahead').typeahead({source: [<%= @cities %>], items:20});
```

But now I want to use an extended version of typeahead that uses an array of kvp objects instead of strings. [This one](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) from tcrosen seems just fine.

I added their [bootstrap-typeahead.js](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-typeahead.js) to app/assests/javascripts folder. Changed the application.js to include that file:

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-typeahead
//= require_tree .
```

But it seems that he's using the typeahead function defined on bootstrap.min.js instead of the new one.

How can I point him to use the right file?

ps: I'm using other bootstrap javascripts plugins so I can't just delete bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying the global file

```
//= require bootstrap
```

you can separately require them :

```
//= require bootstrap-affix
//= require bootstrap-alert
//= require bootstrap-button
//= require bootstrap-carousel
//= require bootstrap-collapse
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-scrollspy
//= require bootstrap-tab
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require bootstrap-transition
```

and so don't include the last one `//= require bootstrap-typeahead`. With that you can require the bootstrap-typeahead javascript file from tcrosen (putting in your asset javascript directory and require it, but don't forget to rename it also, otherwise the old bootstrap typeahead will be use). Tested with bootstrap-sass and tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead.